# Functions: Passing data

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I am reading *A Smarter Way to Learn Javascript* by Mark Myers and it is really helping me learn and understand Javascript.

I am up to chapter 36 and this is the first time I am completely struggling. I don't understand the concept of passing data to functions.

Can someone please explain what is the purpose of passing data?

I really don't even know what else to ask because I am confused by the entire topic.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `alert("hello")` <- here, `"hello"` was passed to the `alert` function

Comment: If the book needs 36 chapters to get to passing data to functions and still doesn't manage to explain it in a way you can understand, consider changing tutorial/book.

Comment: A function is essentially a reusable block of code; the primary point of a function is to avoid duplicate code. However, usually when you do something twice or more, some details might change. That's why you can add parameters to your function, then pass values/data when you call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this.

```
function random(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
console.log(random(0, 6)); //random result between [0-5]
```

You can pass data to functions to make your code more effective. You don't need to copy code of random function every time you need a random number, instead, you create a reusable function that generates all the random numbers in your code.

Comment: How does this in any way address the OP's (off topic) question?

Comment: @Chris G I am passing data to function to describe why this is an important feature of JavaScript. This is just a short example when passing data is useful..

Comment: OP seems to have trouble with the entire concept of functions (which is only introduced in chapter 35). How are nested function calls and random formulas helping with that? It's clear that you mean well, but this answer is not useful.

Comment: @Chris G well, put anything inside the function. The reusable code can be anything. Random function is just a popular example that almost everyone uses at least once. I think a good example is better to resolve the issue. You see a practical solution, you understand that you can use that function without a need to write the same code over and over again in your code. I am not the best teacher or advisor, but I would appreciate answer like this if I were to learn JS and seeing this example.